# CSS Variables - Swapping values?

Tags: css, swap, css-variables

I have a very simple problem with CSS variables. I would like to swap two CSS variables, basically the CSS equivalent of `[a, b] = [b, a]` in ES6. Here's a simple example:

```html
<p>White background</p>
<button>Black background</button>
<div>
  <p>Black background</p>
  <button>White background</button>
</div>
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

button {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

div {
  /* i'd like to do the following: */
  --primary-color: var(--secondary-color);
  --secondary-color: var(--primary-color);

  /* so here, `--primary-color` would be `--secondary-color` from `:root`
   * and any children have these colors swapped as well
   */
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

However, this fails because CSS `var()`s are live bindings. Am I missing something here? Or is this the way the spec currently works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a cyclic dependence because you are defining each property using the other one and this won't work. Instead you may try something like this by introducing more variables:

```css
:root {
  --p:#fff;
  --s:#000;
  --primary-color: var(--p);
  --secondary-color: var(--s);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

button {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

div {
  /* i'd like to do the following: */
  --primary-color: var(--s);
  --secondary-color: var(--p);
  
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<p>White background</p>
<button>Black background</button>
<div>
  <p>Black background</p>
  <button>White background</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What about if I were to embed another div within that one? I'd like it to swap the colors from the first div and apply them to the second. There's definitely no way to do that, right?

Comment: @ArielAbreu well, the solution is to simply avoid cycle :) as CSS is not JS, these are not instruction excuted after each other ... these are property, so if in the same class you have cycle between 2 properties it won't work